# Why does implementing 'IList<T>' require defining two 'GetEnumerator' methods?

Tags: c#, .net, list, interface

When I implement `IList<T>`, I find that I am required to define *two* `GetEnumerator` methods. One returns a value that is of type `IEnumerator`, while the other returns `IEnumerator<T>`.

I'm a little confused about the difference between these two `GetEnumerator` methods. While the return types are obviously different, don't they essentially hold the same data?

In addition, why is it that both versions of `GetEnumerator` can exist as methods when they differ only by return type? This seems to violate the rule in C# which specifies that overloaded methods *cannot* differ only by return type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both should return the same data, yes.

`IEnumerator` is from .Net v1.1, before generic typing was introduced.  `IEnumerator<T>` is the generically typed version added in .Net v2.

The "old" version, `IEnumerator`, has been kept for compatibility, so now `IList<T>` implements both.

The difference between the two is that the non-generic `IEnumerator` returns object's whereas the generic `IEnumerator<T>` returns T's.  Although, the c# compiler will insert a cast for you to make the non-generic `IEnumerator` *seem* strongly-typed when used in a foreach.

The presence of a generic type argument is enough for the compiler to differentiate between the two interfaces, but for a class to implement both one must be explicitly implemented.

Comment: Not quite true, the generic argument isn't enough - one is implemented explicitly, the other isn't.

Comment: I would hardly call the non-Generic use of IEnumerator in a foreach loop magic. It simply attempts a cast from object to the type you specify. If it fails, you'll get an Exception.

Comment: Accepted for explaining the backwards compatability issue. Thanks.

Comment: There is another difference between the two IEnumerator interfaces, besides which type they return: If there is no 'Current' item (if the enumerator is either before or after the list), then `IEnumerator.Current` is supposed to throw an exception, while `IEnumerator<T>.Current` is supposed to return null or default. If you write an enumerator class that implements both interfaces, you'll need to be careful in your implementation of the two Current properties.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx says "Current also throws an exception if the last call to MoveNext returned false, which indicates the end of the collection.", while http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58e146b7.aspx says undefined. Object browser shows this for the non-generic one: "System.InvalidOperationException: The enumerator is positioned before the first element of the collection or after the last element." A look at the `List<T>` enumerator shows it follows those rules.

Answer (score 8):

The two come from separate interfaces that IList itself implements, which is why you have to implement both:

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

And they're both able to exist because of [Explicit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for that link. That helped more than anything.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both methods should return the same data.

They can co-exist because they are part of two different interfaces, `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

They both can exist because one of them will be implemented [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx):

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{

}
```

If you attempt to make them both *implicitly* defined, you will get compile errors.

Yes, they should both return the same data.

You are required to define the two versions of `GetEnumerator` in order to satisfy both interfaces (`IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`) from which `IList<T>` is derived. In practice, however, you tend to find the non-generic version of `GetEnumerator` just calls the generic one in most implementations.

Answer (score 0):

`IList<T>` Implements both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`.  The different implementations of `GetEnumerator` come from each of these interfaces.  Both should return the same data.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerator enumerates objects, whereas IEnumerator enumerates T. For your second question, the second function is fully qualified:

```
  System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()  
  {

  }
```

vs

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {

    }
```